# Tabs layout issue

Tags: bug, new-nav, user-experience

It looks like the tabs are not pretty any more!

> [image]

Environment: Safari version 10.0 (11602.1.50.0.10)

IMHO, a second/third row of tabs instead of this single row would be a much better user experience.

I verified in Chrome, and it seems to be working fine.

> [image]

Comment: wouldn't it be better to include alot of those tags in one tab and search for *any* rather than *all*? like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lveiR.png)

Comment: Are you saying that having this many tabs used to work but something broke it?

Comment: @BSMP Yes. It was not overlapping. Looks like an issue only in safari. Working fine in chrome.

Comment: How do you even see those tabs?

Comment: This should probably also be tagged with [new-nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav).

Comment: Glad we can destroy tabs as well.